# How to perform a k-fold cross validation in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, google-earth-engine, k-fold

I am interested in performing a k-fold cross validation and accuracy assessment for a land cover classification in Google Earth Engine. I have compiled the code below which partitions the training data into a training and testing subset for model development and evaluation, respectively. I am unsure how to modify this code to perform the k-fold cross validation and assess the accuracy of the classification for each of the individual model runs and then the average accuracy across all model runs. Also, would it be possible to use a random seed to ensure that the splits of the training and testing data for the k-fold cross validation are done in the same manner each time the code is run?

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[30.68, -29.54],
      [30.72, -29.54],
      [30.72, -29.41],
      [30.68, -29.41],
      [30.68, -29.54]]]);

var period_of_interest = ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-02-28');

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//Build the Sentinel 2 collection, filtered by date, bounds and percentage of cloud cover 
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filter(period_of_interest)
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10))
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
//1 NDVI (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {   
    var NDVI = image.expression(
        "(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)",
        {
          RED: image.select("B4"),    //  RED
          NIR: image.select("B8"),    // NIR
}).rename('NDVI')
return image.addBands(NDVI)
})

//2 gNDVI (Green Normalized Difference Vegetation Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) { 
var gNDVI = image.expression(
        "(NIR - Green)/(NIR + Green)",
        { NIR: image.select("B8"),   
          Green: image.select("B3"),
}).rename('gNDVI')
return image.addBands(gNDVI)
})
          
//3 NDVIre (Normalized Difference Vegetation Index Red-edge)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var NDVIre = image.expression(
        "(NIR - Rededge1) / (NIR + Rededge1)",
        { NIR: image.select("B8"),   
          Rededge1: image.select("B5"),
}).rename('NDVIre')
return image.addBands(NDVIre)
}); 
          
//4 EVI (Enhanced Vegetation Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
  var EVI = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2')
}).rename('EVI')
return image.addBands(EVI)
})

//5 SAVI (Soil Adjusted Vegetation Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var SAVI = image.expression(
        "((NIRnarrow - RED) / (NIRnarrow + RED + 0.5) * 1.5)",
        {
          NIRnarrow: image.select("B8A"),    
          RED: image.select("B4")    
}).rename('SAVI')
return image.addBands(SAVI)
}); 
          
//6 SR-BlueRededge1 (Simple Blue and Red-edge 1 Ratio)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var SRBlueRededge1 = image.expression(
        "(BLUE / REDedge1)",
        {
          BLUE: image.select("B2"),    
          REDedge1: image.select("B5")    
}).rename('SRBlueRededge1')
return image.addBands(SRBlueRededge1)
}); 

//7 SR-NIRnarrowRededge1 (Simple NIR and Red-edge 1 Ratio)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var SRNIRnarrowRededge1 = image.expression(
        "(NIRnarrow / REDedge1)",
        {
          NIRnarrow: image.select("B8A"),    
          REDedge1: image.select("B5")    
}).rename('SRNIRnarrowRededge1')
return image.addBands(SRNIRnarrowRededge1)
}); 

//8 Pigment Specific Simple Ratio (chlorophyll index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var PSSRa = image.expression(
        "(NIR / RED)",
        { NIR: image.select("B8"),    
          RED: image.select("B4")    
}).rename('PSSRa')
return image.addBands(PSSRa)
}); 
        
//9 Chlogreen (Chlorophyll Green Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var GCI = image.expression(
        "((NIR/Green))-1",
        {
          NIR: image.select("B8"),    
          Green: image.select("B3"),    
}).rename('GCI')
return image.addBands(GCI)
});
        
//10 BAI
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var BAI = image.expression(
        "(Blue - NIR)/(Blue + NIR)",
        { Blue: image.select("B2"),   
          NIR: image.select("B8"),    
}).rename('BAI')
return image.addBands(BAI)
});

//11 Lcaroc (Leaf Carotenoid Content)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var Lcaroc = image.expression(
        "(Rededge3) / (Blue - Rededge1)",
        { Rededge3: image.select("B7"),    
          Blue: image.select("B2"),    
          Rededge1: image.select("B5"),    
          }).rename('Lcaroc')
return image.addBands(Lcaroc)
});

//12 Lchloc (Leaf Chlorophyll Content)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var Lchloc = image.expression(
        "(Rededge3) / (Rededge1)",
        { Rededge3: image.select("B7"),    
          Rededge1: image.select("B5"),    
          }).rename('Lchloc')
return image.addBands(Lchloc)
});

//13 LAnthoC (Leaf Anthocynanid Content)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var Lanthoc = image.expression(
        "(Rededge3) / (Green + Rededge1)",
        { Rededge3: image.select("B7"),
          Green: image.select("B3"),
          Rededge1: image.select("B5"),    
          }).rename('Lanthoc')
return image.addBands(Lanthoc)
});

//14 Mcari (Modified Chlorophyll Absorption in Reflectance Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var Mcari = image.expression(
        "((Rededge1-Red)-0.2*(Rededge1-Green))*(Rededge1/Red)",
        { Red: image.select("B4"),
          Green: image.select("B3"),
          Rededge1: image.select("B5"),    
          }).rename('Mcari')
return image.addBands(Mcari)
});

//15 PSRI (Plant Senescence Reflectance Index)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var PSRI = image.expression(
        "(Red-Green)/Rededge2",
        { Red: image.select("B4"),
          Green: image.select("B3"),
          Rededge2: image.select("B6"),    
          }).rename('PSRI')
return image.addBands(PSRI)
});

//16 PPR (Plant Pigment Ratio)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var PPR = image.expression(
        "(Green-Blue)/(Green+Blue)",
        { Green: image.select("B3"),
          Blue: image.select("B2"),    
          }).rename('PPR')
return image.addBands(PPR)
});

//17 PVR (Photosyntetic Vigour Ratio)
var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image) {
var PVR = image.expression(
        "(Green-Red)/(Green+Red)",
        { Green: image.select("B3"),
          Red: image.select("B4"),    
          }).rename('PVR')
return image.addBands(PVR)
});

var image = imageCollection.median()
print("Final_image", image);

// Create training data
var LULC = ee.FeatureCollection('users/shaedengokool/points')
Map.addLayer(LULC.style({color: 'black', fillColor: '00000000'}), false)
print (LULC)

var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI',
            'gNDVI','NDVIre', 'EVI', 'SAVI', 'SRBlueRededge1', "SRNIRnarrowRededge1", 
            'PSSRa', 'GCI', 'BAI', 'Lcaroc', 'Lchloc', 'Lanthoc', 'Mcari', 'PSRI', 'PPR', 'PVR']
var training_data = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
collection: LULC, 
  properties: ['Id'], 
  geometries: true,
  scale: 10.00,
  tileScale: 16, 
});
print(training_data, "training_data")

// Reserve some of the data for validation.
var withRandom = training_data.randomColumn('random', 1)//1 is a random number generator for reproducability
var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% validation.
var training_subset = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var validation_subset = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));
print(training_subset, 'training_subset')
print(validation_subset, 'validation_subset')

// Train and run the classifier with the training data (70% of the full record)
// Select and uncomment the classifier from the list below to use in the classification

//1. Gradient Tree Boost
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileGradientTreeBoost(300).train({
  features: training_subset, 
  classProperty: 'Id', 
  inputProperties: bands
});
// Run the classification
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);

// Re-substituion accuracy of classification 
var confMatrix = classifier.confusionMatrix();

var OA = confMatrix.accuracy();
var CA = confMatrix.consumersAccuracy();
var Kappa = confMatrix.kappa();
var Order = confMatrix.order();
var PA = confMatrix.producersAccuracy();

print(Order,'Order');
print(confMatrix,'Confusion Matrix');
print(PA,'Producers Accuracy');
print(CA,'Consumers Accuracy');
print(OA,'Overall Accuracy');
print(Kappa,'Kappa');

// Classify the validation FeatureCollection
var validation = validation_subset.classify(classifier);

var confMatrix2 = validation.errorMatrix('Id', 'classification');

var OA2 = confMatrix2.accuracy();
var CA2 = confMatrix2.consumersAccuracy();
var Kappa2 = confMatrix2.kappa();
var Order2 = confMatrix2.order();
var PA2 = confMatrix2.producersAccuracy();

print(Order2,'Order2');
print(confMatrix2,'Confusion Matrix2');
print(PA2,'Producers Accuracy2');
print(CA2,'Consumers Accuracy2');
print(OA2,'Overall Accuracy2');
print(Kappa2,'Kappa2');
```